# Collecting data(images) using a crawler

Tags: machine-learning

Please let me know, if this goes here, if not, please point out where I should post this. Thanks in advance.

So I require huge number of training data, mostly images. This is a pet project, only for learning. So how and where do I collect them, free of cost?

Will it be suitable if I use a crawler and pull out images, tagged with, say for example: "Cat". Or is there another way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think requests for such data sets are offtopic; likely answers include "get a smart dump from Flickr (or similar)" which is not a problem of science, but technology.

Comment: I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but a lot of computer vision and machine learning researchers are using http://www.image-net.org/

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a license? What kind of images do you need? Images of animals?

If you want to start small, you can try images of hand-written digits:
http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

If that is not what your looking for, you have different options depending on your system. For Linux I myself use wget. It works like a charm and is fairly easy to use.

Like so:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder

It takes only a few hours to learn how to make a shell script, to download in bulk.